# Python TCP socket and syslog

Tags: python, rsyslog

I'm baffled as to why I can't get rsyslog to log data sent to it via TCP whenever I send the data with a Python script, but works perfectly fine if I send the same string via netcat

Rsyslog is set up to receive syslog data on TCP/514:
/etc/rsyslog.conf

```
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514
```

/etc/rsyslog.d/LogByIP.conf

```
$template LogByIP,"/tmp/%fromhost-ip%.log"

if ($fromhost-ip != '127.0.0.1') then ?LogByIP
```

Restarted rsyslog. Executed this command from the client machine:

```
[root@localhost ~]# echo HELLO2 |nc logbox 514
```

Contents of /tmp/.log

```
Nov 18 15:36:16 HELLO2
```

So rsyslog is working as expected. Now when I try to do the same thing in Python, the message never gets written to file.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import socket

host='logbox'
port=514
message='hello world'

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host,port))
s.sendall(message)
s.close()
```

Running tcpdump on the logbox, I can see the session setup, the string transmitted and the session closed out in TCP, but "hello world" never shows up in the logfile. What am I missing here?

Comment: Just as a random guess, I noticed the shell script will append an enter (\n), and the python code won't. echo -n sends text without the trailing \n.

Comment: Adding a \n at the end of the string solved the problem. Thank you!